# Dump results from bitcoin-qt debug console to file

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cli

I would like to issue some commands in the Bitcoin-qt console and save their output to a text file (ideally, filter it before saving). Is there a way to do that, similar to how I would use `grep` and `>` in a regular Linux terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `bitcoin-cli`, and update your `bitcoin.conf` to enable the RPC server. `bitcoin-cli` will let you pipe the output from the commands through to any shell commands you want, or redirect to a file.